# How to remove a formula and keep only value in a cell using python openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel-formula, formula, openpyxl

I want to remove the formula "=LEFT(C2,SEARCH(",",C2))" (cell value is 5/23/2019,) and keep only its value so that I could calculate the age later on.

With my above code I have extracted the date from cell 'B2' with comma using the formula:

```
 '=LEFT(B2,SEARCH(",",B2))'
```

Now, I need to remove the formula and keep only the value in cell 'C2' to calculate the TT age in cell 'D2' using the formula:

```
'=A2-C2'
```

*Note: cell 'A2' has today's date.*

But I am unable to remove the formula and keep only the value in the cell 'C2'

```
import os

import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Prac.xlsx")

sheet1 = wb['Sheet1']

sheet1['C2'] = '=LEFT(B2,SEARCH(",",B2))'
```

I expect the value of cell 'C2' to be "5/12/2019," and not the formula itself.
Please find the link to my screenshot of the excel sheet here. [Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZQ7x.png)

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Comment: Yes. It speaks about writing a formula to a cell but I could not find any informtion about removing a formula from a cell.

Comment: try to do : `=DATEVALUE(LEFT(B2,SEARCH(",",B2)))` in the excel file ...